# Splitting a string into words and doubles

Tags: java, arrays, regex, split

I am writing a program to read a file that looks like this:

NODE: label Buenous Aires:x=131.3456:y=-48.783

I want the program to split each line into an array with the entries of the label, then the x value, and the y value. I have looked into using the s.split tool with regular expressions but I do not know how to store the information that I am reading in into the program.

```
String[] words=s.split(" ");
"NODE: label=(.+):x=(\d+):y=(\d+)";
```

Could someone please give me tips on how to make such an array.
I am looking for the array to have 3 entries, the first the label Buenous Aires, the second the x value and the third the y value.

Comment: post your data as text and representation of expected output

Comment: You're not extracting a regex at all. You've just made a string and not assigned it to anything. And your label contains spaces, so you don't want to split on that

Comment: Can you post a part of your file with a few entries and specify what you want in each index of the array for this input.

Comment: With your edit that changed the file picture to text, you also, presumably inadvertently, changed the `=` after `label` to a space.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not comfortable with regex, you could instead

1. Split on colons
2. Loop over those strings (start at position 1)
3. Split on equal signs
4. Extract your data

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `split()` (which is a good idea, since it can directly yield the wanted string array), you have not to specify the overall pattern of the string like you intended with `"NODE: label=(.+):x=(\d+):y=(\d+)"`, but only a delimiting expression, as `:.=`:

- `:` - ends the previous entry
- `.` - matches `x` or `y`
- `=` - preludes the next entry

---

```
    String s = "NODE: label=Buenous Aires:x=131.3456:y=-48.783";
    String[] words = s.substring(12).split(":.=");
```

The `substring(12)` skips the leading `NODE: label=`.